# Possible to Move In-house Windows Server to Azure Equivalent ( Cloud )?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, windows-server

We have an old SBS2008 server that is on the way out. We only use it for Authentication as all our apps are in the cloud now. Is it possible to be done with an in-house server altogether and use cloud services to do some/all of what SBS does?  Has anybody done this?

[my thoughts so far]
Azure Active directory Looks like it might do the authentication part, and very cost effective.

Azure Domains services look like it might to the Group policy part, but looks expensive ( probably more expensive than a server for a small business).

Azure DNS looks like it might do the DNS part and cost effective as well.

Obviously, DHCP would now go on the router

Please don't shut this question down, I need a helpful answer to a specific question, I will reword it if need be ( just comment ). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look at your overall roadmap and strategy for the company really, rather than just replacing what you have with new technologies.

I'd recommend that you try and move away from using ADDS and modernize workstations to Windows 10, being Azure AD joined.  Move away from Group Policy, and look at using Intune for policy management.

For your cloud apps, look at using Azure AD for authentication and not something like ldap or the sorts.  Basically, standardize using Azure AD for auth across all your access mediums, and stay away from traditional AD or using ADDS.

These recommendations might seem drastic and rather large effort, however if your company is running SBS still, it might be that you have a low enough amount of apps and infrastructure to take on a transformational change.

Comment: Awesome , thanks - really appreciate your time.  Will make an effort to move out of the dark ages ;-)